# SQL. Как запросить данные из другой таблицы и отобразить в текущей?

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в стобцах serv_id,type,combo_select присутствуют значения ID из других таблиц.
Например serv_id - это ID из таблицы services.
Как бы составить такой запрос,в котором я получу такую же текущую страницу но вместо id в этих столбцах будут соответствующие наименования из соответствующих им таблиц?
Спасибо заранее 
**P.S. Как быть с значениями через запятую как в serv_id? Без него все делается через LEFT OUTER JOIN, но как быть с ним все таки?**

Comment: а не надо таким образом вообще данные хранить, чтобы вопросы такие потом не задавать и проблем не хватать.

Comment: Нормализуйте данные - и проблема отпадёт сама собой.

Answer (score 0):

Формально - если данные денормализованы, и некое поле содержит comma-separated values, то есть как минимум два варианта организации связи по такому полю.

**Первый вариант** - проверка на вхождение подстроки. Для корректной обработки первого и последнего тегов как данные, так и шаблон обрамляются дополнительными разделителями, т.е.

```
WHERE INSTR(CONCAT(',', field_where_to_search, ','), CONCAT(',', field_what_to_search, ','))
```

Если тег присутствует в списке, возвращается его позиция в списке, что интерпретируется как True, если его нет, возвращается ноль, интерпретируемый как False. Разделитель в общем может быть любой - лишь бы его не было в значениях элементов списка.

**Второй вариант** - поиск в списке.

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(field_what_to_search, field_where_to_search)
```

Принцип тот же самый, только возвращается не позиция в строке, а порядковый номер в списке. Недостаток метода - разделитель строго запятая (впрочем, никто не мешает заменить текущий разделитель на запятую, лишь бы её не было в теле самих тегов).

**Оба способа - плохие**. Тем, что использование индексов невозможно, и поиск ведётся сканированием таблицы (или, если повезёт, покрывающего индекса).

Имеются и иные варианты решения задачи, но все они далеки от оптимальных. Лучше нормализовать данные.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!